# Python 3.8 Windows: print produces UnicodeEncodeError when piping

Tags: python, windows, console, python-3.8

Although Python 3.8 should use UTF-8 also on Windows
([PEP-0528](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0528)
[PEP-0529](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0529)),
one still gets

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u251c' in position 0: character maps to <undefined>
```

The exception happens in `cp1252.py`.

Example code (`t.py`):

```py
print(b'\xe2\x94\x9c'.decode('utf-8'))
print(b'\xe2\x94\x94'.decode('utf-8'))
print(b'\xe2\x94\x80'.decode('utf-8'))
print(b'\xe2\x94\x82'.decode('utf-8'))
```

It does not happen with `python t.py`,
but it happens when piping

```
python t.py | python -c "import sys; print(sys.stdin.read())"
```

or forwarding to a file (`python t.py > t.txt`).

Answer (score 0):

Adding

```py
import sys
import codecs
try:
    sys.stdin = codecs.getreader("utf-8")(sys.stdin.detach())
    sys.stdout = codecs.getwriter("utf-8")(sys.stdout.detach())
except:
    pass

print(b'\xe2\x94\x9c'.decode('utf-8'))
```

from one of the answers further down in this post helps:

[Python, Unicode, and the Windows console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5419/python-unicode-and-the-windows-console)

The try-except is useful when using py.test,
as there is a conflict with py.test capsys,
that makes replacing `sys.stdout` fail.

Comment: For redirected standard I/O, you can override the ANSI default via the `PYTHONIOENCODING` environment variable (see the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#environment-variables)). More radically, you can set the `PYTHONUTF8` environment variable for 3.7+. This forces `locale.getpreferredencoding()` to UTF-8, which overrides the default for all files.

Comment: Thanks for the info. One has no influence on the environment of a package user, though.

Comment: A package shouldn't modify the standard streams, unless it's a voluntary, opt-in configuration. Python's documented behavior is to use `locale.getpreferredencoding()` when opening files, unless overridden by `PYTHONIOENCODING` for stdin, stdout, and stderr. In Windows, this is the system ANSI codepage. An exception is made for the Windows console. By default, Python 3.6+ uses the console's UTF-16 API and presents this to scripts as a UTF-8 file. But if `PYTHONLEGACYWINDOWSSTDIO` is defined, it uses the legacy console codepage instead (OEM, typically), as do Python versions prior to 3.6.